# iPhone Flipside Template (Utility Application): Where did the view come from?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

When I start a project with the *Utility Application Template* (which has a flipview), I get 3 .xib files.

When I open the "MainWindow.xib", I get two rectangular pieces. One of them represents the window. The other is called `RootViewController`. This has a view in it.

My question is :

1) How is this view represented, because there is no View object in the Document Window of IB ?

2) How is it added to the `ViewController` from IB because whenever I add a `ViewController`, I get an empty area (cross shaded with grey stripes) ?

Answer (score 0):

The RootViewController simply is responsible for loading the other ViewControllers. Look in the ViewControllers folder to find them. Those view controllers contain the views. The reason this is done is so that you can have multiple views per view controller.

Comment: I know that. My question is about the MainWindow.xib document which shows a UIView in the UIViewController (more precisely, RootViewController). Where did that come from ?

Answer (score -1):

Look to auto-created files in your project

UntitledAppDelegate.m and RootViewController.m

Answer is there